# How do I implement a 30-day cutoff in the Chow test to analyze changes in time series data after a significant event?

Tags: python, time-series, data-science, data-analysis

I am using the [Chow test](https://github.com/David-Woroniuk/chowtest) python library to analyze structural change in time series data potentially caused by a significant event. Since each data point represents a day, I set `last_index` to the day before the event and `first_index` to the event. This means the data is broken into two chunks:

- Chunk 1: All data occurring before the event
- Chunk 2: All data occurring on and after the event
  This is working fine, but I also want to analyze potential changes in the 30-day period following the significant event. In other words, I want to use a cutoff of 30 days rather than a single day, if that makes sense.

So far, I have tried to create a larger period cutoff by setting `first_index` to 30 days after the event. This means the data is broken into two chunks:

- Chunk 1: All data occurring before the event
- Chunk 2: All data occurring 30 days later and beyond
  This excludes data occurring in days 1-29. Is it better to exclude the data in this period, or is it better to keep the data when conducting the Chow test with a 30-day cutoff? Should I be using multi-cutoff analysis, where the first cutoff is the event and the second cutoff is 30 days following the event?
  tl;dr: If I want to use the Chow test to analyze changes that occurred 30 days after an event in the data, what's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. It is not possible to provide a specific answer without you providing sufficient information to understand your problem. Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.

Comment: @itprorh66 my apologies, I wasn't sure how to phrase my question. I'm not looking for someone to write code for me, this is more of a theory question. Also, I'm not a student looking for homework help, in case that matters. Is my implementation of the Chow test valid for analyzing structural changes 30 days after an event? If there's a better way to do this, I can code it myself. If I need to provide more information, please let me know.

Comment: This site is devoted to assisting with programming related problems, questions related to the theory of statistical analysis are not within our scope.